# Accessing data mapper variable in PHP?

Tags: php, datamapper

I have an application in MVC. I want to get the user's first name by ID. I have a function to do this

```
function getNameById($id = null) {
    if ($id !== null) {
       // get name by ID from database
       return $id;
    } else {
        // get name by SESSION ID from database
       return $id;
    }
}
```

but I see people call the function like this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->getNameById();
```

but I don't know how to do if statements like this. I put mine in a variable. Is this corrrect use?

```
$user = new User();
$fname = $user->getNameById();
```

Comment: The funtion returns a value, what you do with it it up to you??

Comment: I understand it returns a value. Is it correct MVC to do an if statement such as `if ($this->userMapper->getNameById() === 'Bill')`? And I want to access it from the template.

Comment: 'this' is nothing but refer a current class ... so it you have nay class then create the object of that class and assign vale to particulate variable. Example : class a{ public function getUserNameById(){return "your name";}} then create the object of that class like $object=new a(); and call the function just like $username=$object->getUserNameById(); .. now you done

Comment: Right and that is correct way to use Data Mapper? I have learned OOP but am a little new to Data Mapping, Domain Objects Etc. @Code_Crash

Comment: ya right.. and u also correct in you code

Comment: @user1475632 actually it isn't. Correct use would be: `$mapper = new UserMapper; $user = new User; $user->setId(42); $mapper->fetch($user);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using correctly on this specific case.

For if's

```
$user = new User();
if($usernames = $user->getNameById(1)) {
    //find and store into $usernames
}
else {
}
```

Comment: OK. I am calling that from the controller. Should I call the Data Mapper from the Controller? Or should I have the model do that.

Comment: Better let the model do that. Data Mapper is between Model and Database. Controller -> Model -> DataMapper -> Physic Database.